# Django (?P<pk>\d+) vs <int:pk>

Tags: python, django

I have this **post_list.html** file: (Ignore the second 'blog:post_detail' url)

```
{% for post in post_list %}
  <h1><a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
  <div class="date">
    <p>Published on: {{post.published|date:"D M Y"}}</p>
  </div>
  <a href="{url 'blog:post_detail' post.pk}">Comments: {{post.approve_comments.count}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And in the **urls.py** I am trying to use **re_path** in the following way:

```
re_path(r'^posts/<int:pk>/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

When I run the server I am getting **NoReverseMatch at /** error:`Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/<int:pk>/$']`

---

However if I replace **re_path** with **url** and `<int:pk>` with `(?P<pk>\d+)` it works perfectly:

```
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong function. `re_path` is an alias for `url`, so it uses the old regex syntax. If you want to use the new syntax, use `path`.

Answer (score 6):

because your django is not 2.0+

## django >=2.0

django 2.0 recommended use path

```
path(r'^posts/<int:pk>/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail')
```

if you want to use regular expression, like django<2.0

```
re_path(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

## django<2.0

```
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```